# Unable to lock Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: password, 15.04, lock-screen

I have ubuntu 15.04. When I press alt+ctrl+l to lock my ubuntu, a black screen appears with my mouse pointer. When I start to move to pointer the black screen goes and ubuntu desktop appears(as if it was not locked just went to sleep).
Similarly I tried locking it from the top right menu-->lock, where we can shut down and log out.
I have changed my password and ensured that it asks for password while logging in but still when i restart it doesn't ask for a password.
Any solutions ?

Comment: You may need to setup the keyboard shortcut in keyboard settings to lock the screen - you may also need to [disable passwordless login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94867/how-can-i-disable-passwordless-login). Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Yes I have checked it, its atl+trl+l but still a black screen with mouse pointer visible. I can't post a pic because i need atleast 10 reputaion.

Answer (score 0):

when you remove password of existing user for passwordless login.
ubuntu add that user into nopasswdlogin  group which means no password will be asked for login or lock screen but on command line password required for sudo etc.

Remove the user from `nopasswdlogin` group

```
sudo gpasswd -d *USERNAME*  nopasswdlogin
```

replace *USERNAME* with appropriate user name